# When the Bitmap is scaled, it goes like this

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I have an image drawn in the picturebox and I need to scale it using a trackbar. But this happens whenever I scale it up, and if I continue scaling - it becomes more blurry.

[image]

My code:

**Image Drawing**

```
public LayerClass ImageDrawing(LayerClass.Type img, Bitmap bm, Rectangle imgRect, String filepath, int angle, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        bm = ImageClass.GrayscaleImage(bm);
        bm = MakeTransparentImage(bm);

        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        bm = RotateImage(bm, angle);
        imgRect = new Rectangle((int)(Shape.center.X - (bm.Width / 2)), (int)(Shape.center.Y - (bm.Height / 2)), (int)bm.Width, (int)bm.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), imgRect);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, imgRect);

        this.imageBitmap = bm;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.rotationAngle = angle;
        this.location = location;
        this.imageRect = imgRect;
        return new LayerClass(LayerClass.Type.Image, this, filePath, imgRect);
    }
```

**Scaling**

```
    private void trackBar_ScaleImg_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Width Scaling
            if(rb_WidthImage.Checked)
            {
                imgRect.Width = trackBar_ScaleImg.Value;
                imgRect.X = (int)(Shape.center.X - (imgRect.Width / 2));
                lbl_imgWidth.Text = Math.Round((trackBar_ScaleImg.Value * 25.4) / 96).ToString();
                toolTip_Scroll.SetToolTip(trackBar_ScaleImg, lbl_imgWidth.Text);

                ImageBitmap = new Bitmap(ImageBitmap, new Size(imgRect.Width, imgRect.Height));
            }
}
```

Comment: Whats your definition of this happens. It changes aspect ratio? or just becomes blury

Comment: The Image resizes but also becomes blurry.

Comment: It is normal that if you zoom in too close on any given image, it first becomes blurry. Then pixelated. That is in the nature of digital images. It is also worth noting that images in you app memory are not compressed. Compression applies to disk storage and network transfer. Any image in memory takes up widht x height x color depth.

Comment: @Christopher different thing is happening, if I scale it up an down a lot if times, it becomes like this https://imgur.com/a/LUGCxig

Comment: This is quite normal. Don't scale up or down repeatedly. Instead keep a copy of the original and only use this as the source for the scaling!!

Comment: @TaW how do I do that?

Comment: I mean use the the Bitmap for scaling and the copy for preserving the image.

Comment: Just keep the original bitmap in a separate variable and don't change it, and only show a manipulated copy.